# Saving a modified workbook with openpyxl gives a KeyError

Tags: python, openpyxl

i have this strange issue when reading/modifying and at last saving an existing xlsx file with openpyxl. See first the error msg that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/storage/share/qfotoka/general_main.py", line 260, in saveTestRecord
    workbook.save(filepath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/workbook.py", line 265, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 187, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 170, in save
    self.write_data(archive)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 98, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive, shared_string_table, self.style_writer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 128, in _write_worksheets
    style_writer.get_style_by_hash()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/worksheet.py", line 98, in write_worksheet
    write_worksheet_cols(doc, worksheet, style_table)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl-1.8.2/openpyxl/writer/worksheet.py", line 209, in write_worksheet_cols
    col_def['style'] = str(style_table[hash(columndimension.style_index)])
KeyError: -8937945243006069197
```

As you can see i don't do much with the xlsx file. Since the max_cols in my excel file is 'E', i add some values in E1-H3.

Here is my sample.xlsx file, sorry can't yet post images:

```
A     B   C  D
Area  Test    Prio   Selected ?
ZZZ   ZZZ011  1.1.0  x
XXX   XXX012  1.1.0  x
```

Thanks in adv.

My code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.style import Color, Fill
from openpyxl.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string, Cell

def saveTestRecord(filepath, sheetName, results=None):
    try:
         workbook = load_workbook(filename=filepath,guess_types=False)
         sheets = workbook.get_sheet_names()
         for i in sheets:
             if i == sheetName:
                 print "Sheet: %s found"%(i)
                 sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(i)
    except:
         print "Problem reading excel file: %s or no sheet found with pattern: %s"%(filepath, sheetName)
         exit
    max_cols = 0.0
    for row in sheet.rows:
        max_cols = float(sheet.get_highest_column())
    starting_col = chr(65 + int(max_cols))
    if max_cols % 4.0 == 0.0: createNewResultsSet(sheet, starting_col)
    workbook.save(filepath)

def createNewResultsSet(sheet, startPos):
    sheet.cell(startPos + '1').value = ''
    sheet.cell(startPos + '2').value = 'Started'
    sheet.cell(startPos + '3').value = ''
    nextPos = chr(ord(startPos) + 1)
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '1').value = ''
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '2').value = 'Ended'
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '3').value = ''
    nextPos = chr(ord(nextPos) + 1)
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '1').value = 'Status'
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '2').value = 'Verdict'
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '3').value = ''
    nextPos = chr(ord(nextPos) + 1)
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '1').value = ''
    sheet.cell(nextPos + '2').value = 'Note'
```

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/53/keyerror-for-styles-when-writing-a ?

Comment: What version of openpyxl? The `KeyError` with styles should be fixed in 1.8.5. If not please submit a bug report.

Comment: Hi, indeed i am using 1.8.2 still. I will switch to the latest!